# C# Taking a listbox with many values, and dividing it up into mulitple text files

Tags: c#, listbox

I am having the hardest time figuring out how to do this.

I have a `listbox` with a lot of data in it. I want to take this `listbox` and then have a button to save it.

The button will choose the directory to put the files in. Afterwards, the program should start saving these values into a text file with the naming schema *Seed1.txt*, *Seed2.txt*, etc.

The thing is, I would like to put only 100 items into each text file that is generated until the list is done.

For saving the path I have:

```
        Stream s;
        string folderPath = string.Empty;

        using (FolderBrowserDialog fdb = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            if (fdb.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                folderPath = fdb.SelectedPath;
                MessageBox.Show(folderPath);

            }
```

For saving everything in one shot, I believe this will work:

```
         int total = list_failed.Items.Count;
           for (int i = 0; i < list_failed.Items.Count; i++)
            {

                StreamWriter text = new StreamWriter(s);
                text.Write(list_failed.Items[i]);
                s.Close();
```

I'm not sure about the rest though.  Something like this for the filenames perhaps

```
          string filename;
            int i = 0;
            do
            {
                filename = "Seed" + ++i + ".txt";
            } while (files.Contains(filename));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    string folderPath;
    const int ITEMS_PER_FILE=100;
    void AskUserForFolder()
    {
        folderPath = string.Empty;

        using (FolderBrowserDialog fdb = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            if (fdb.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                folderPath = fdb.SelectedPath;
                // MessageBox.Show(folderPath);

            }
        }
    }

    void SaveItems(ListBox listBox, int seed)
    {

        int total = listBox.Items.Count;

        for ( int fileCount=0;fileCount<listBox.Items.Count/ITEMS_PER_FILE;++fileCount)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(folderPath + "\\" + GetFilePath(folderPath, "filename.txt",ref seed)))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < listBox.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(listBox.Items[i+(ITEMS_PER_FILE*fileCount)]);
                }
                sw.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    //I'm not sure about the rest though. Something like this for the filenames perhaps
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a filename that has not been used before by incrementing a number at the end of the filename
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="seed">seed is passed in as a referrect value and acts as a starting point to itterate through the list
    /// By passing it in as a reference we can save ourselves from having to itterate unneccssarily for the start each time
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>the path of the file</returns>
    string GetFilePath(string folderpath, string fileName,string extension,ref int seed)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(string.Format("{0}\\{1}{2}.{3}", folderPath, fileName, seed,extension));
        while (fi.Exists)
        {
            fi = new FileInfo(string.Format("{0}\\{1}{2}.{3}", folderPath, fileName, ++seed,extension));
        }
        return fi.FullName;
    }
```

Comment: I'm having a problem with last bracket of code that creates the file, Visual Studio is giving me a "new expression requires (), [], or {}

Comment: I noticed the edit, and just wanted to thank you. I am going to experiment with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to iterate over ListBox items and put them in files with up to 100 items:

```
       private void writeItemsToFile(ListBox lb)
        {
        string path = @"c:\test\";
        string filename = "seed";
        int itemCounter = 0;
        int fileCounter = 1;
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(System.IO.Path.Combine(path,string.Format(filename+"{0}.txt",fileCounter))));
        foreach (var s in lb.Items)
            {
            if (itemCounter > 100)
                {
                fileCounter++;
                itemCounter = 0;
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
                sw.Dispose();
                sw = null;
                sw = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(System.IO.Path.Combine(path,string.Format(filename+"{0}.txt",fileCounter))));
                }
            sw.WriteLine(s.ToString());
            itemCounter++;
            }
        if (sw != null)
            {
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I am trying Paul's recommendation first. I will get back to you soon.

Comment: If I wanted to use a dynamic path with an open-file dialog, would replacing the hard coded path with my variable folderPath work?

Comment: @Mike Yes, definitetely, you can change method to accept path and filename: private private void writeItemsToFile(ListBox lb, string path, string filename)

Comment: If I put that code into a button instead of its own private void, with the original code I used for FolderBrowseDialog, I then replace the hard coded path with my variable folderPath, but it doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Mike try stepping through it. Are you getting any errors? Is you list box bound to specific type of objects or just text items?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, when I stepped through it the issue is that instead of for example, if I choose Downloads as the directory, the application will put the seed file in the upper directory of it.  So instead of placing Seed#.txt in Downloads, it would put DownloadsSeed#.txt in My Documents.  I hope that makes sense.  Seems my issue is with getting the full folder path.

Comment: @Mike it seems you are missing "\" at the end of your folder path

Comment: that's exactly what it looks like.  But I don't see how it is being left out.  Maybe I need to add that / to the way I retrieve it.  But if you look at the code posted to retrieve the folder, I thought that would grab the full path correctly already.

Comment: @Mike This is because FolderBrowserDialog by default returns folder path without backslash at the end. Try adding it or Use Path.Combine() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx

Comment: @Mike I edited my original answer to cater for the way FolderBrowserDialog works

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I added + "\\" to the path selected bit, and it worked!

Edit: just noticed your change lol

Thanks for the help, I appreciate your time.

Comment: Krasinksi Hey Kamil, I wanted to ask you, if I wanted to increment the numbers by the following: 0-9 in the file becomes 0 and then the number.  So for example.  I create Hosts1, Hosts2, Hosts3, etc.  It saves as Hosts01, Hosts02, Hosts03, but then when it reaches 10 and beyond, it drops that first 0.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example that you can use.

```
        string pathname = Server.MapPath("/");
        int counter = 1;
        string file = String.Empty;

        List<string> list = new List<string>();


        //Add the list items
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1234; i++)
        {
            list.Add(String.Format("item {0}", i));
        }


        //write to file
        for (int i = 1; i < list.Count(); i++)
        {
            //generate a dynamic filename with path
            file = String.Format("{0}Seed{1}.txt", pathname, counter);

            //the using statement closes the streamwriter when it completes the process
            using (StreamWriter text = new StreamWriter(file, true))
            {
                //write the line
                text.Write(list[i]);
            }

            //check to see if the max lines have been written
            if (i == counter * 100) counter++;                
        }
```

Comment: Hey @lan

Thank you for the response, I've gone so far with Kamil's code.  I do thank you for your input and I will be keeping that code snippet handy for future use.